# Create a Python deployment package for Lambda on Windows

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need to create a Python deployment package for Lambda.

I notices that I cannot just pip -l ... the requirements I need and then ZIP the folder. Rather, I have to do it on an EC2 instance, and use the resulting folder instead (which contains other binaries that Windows pip does not install, e.g. scipy.libs\libopenblasp-r0-39a31c03.2.18.so for Scipy).

- Is there a way to create a deployment package on Windows?
- If not, can I use some other Linux variants (other than Amazon Linux)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - Is there a way to create a deployment package on Windows?

You can try [running Amazon Linux in a Docker container](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/amazon_linux_container_image.html) inside Windows.

> - If not, can I use some other Linux variants (other than Amazon Linux)?

It has to be Amazon Linux since that's the OS the Lambda function will be running on.